# Is it possible to throttle the main job and not the sub tasks

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Is it possible to use the throttle-concurrent-builds-plugin in a jenkins pipeline job in a way that the job itself is limited to 2 builds per node and the parallel tasks in the testphase are not?

To make it clear a short example:

```
throttle(['myThrottleCategory']) {
node('testnode') {
    try {
           stage 'checkout scm'
           ....

           def tasks [:]
           tasks[0] = {
               stage 'parallel test module A'
               ...
           }
           tasks[1] = ...
           parallel tasks
          }
       } 
    }
```

The main job is throttled to avoid deadlocks and increase the performance. The sub-tasks shouldn´t be throttled, so the job can use all available executors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution i put the sub-tasks on a seperate job, which uses maven repository and workspace of the main job. The sub-tasks run on the same node only. In this way i can throttle the main job and not the sub-tasks/jobs running on other executors of the same node.